# Twitter bootsptrap v3 Camera icon unicode showing rectangle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Im using the glyphicons Halfings Font via font face. (downloaded with twitter bootstap v3) When y tried to use the unicode for the camera, i cant get it to work... a rectanlgle shows up while other icons do show up.

This code results as expected, displays the trash can:

```
<span style='font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings"; font-size: 50px;'>&#xE020;</span>
```

but this:

```
<span style='font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings"; font-size: 50px;'>&#x1F4F7;</span>
```

instead of the displaying the camera, shows a rectangle.

Any help appriciated!

thanks!

Pancho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... found the solution! Turns out that in the font files used for bootstrap, the unicodes were changed for some of the icons. I understand they did this because of some issues with browser compatibility.

Here is the list of modfied/new unicodes:

lock - E033
bookmark - E044
camera - E046
fire - E104
bell - E123
wrench - E136
briefcase - E139
paperclip - E142
pushpin - E146

Found this info on a [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106) on twitter-bootstraps github proyect, check the link for details.

Hope it helps someone...

Pancho